# PHP content does not switch to other language anymore (Polylang)

Tags: php

Hello I m using Polylang and this php code to switch my slider (I did with Smart Slider) to english-french. I don't know anything about PHP but I got it on a forum. It was working perfectly until yesterday.

http://www.chooseyourtelescope.com/

```
<?php
$currentlang = get_bloginfo('language');
if($currentlang=="fr_FR"):
?>
    <div>
        <?php 
        echo do_shortcode('[smartslider3 slider=6]');
        ?>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div>
        <?php 
        echo do_shortcode('[smartslider3 slider=4]');
        ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now it stays in english. I dont think the problem is coming from Smart Slider. I tried to deactivate the other plugins and to restore the previous theme and Polylang versions but nothing changed.

BTW my site is responsive and the slider is not displaying under 800px width. So you can't see the problem on mobile for example.

Comment: looks like it works to me, just make sure your browser isn't translating it before you notice. On a side note, there were some major issues with your site on the initial load, looked half built until I click on something.

Comment: I m on Chrome. I tried with Firefox and IE and still not working. The page is translated but not the slider. Also I dont have any issues with loading on the three browsers..

Comment: This has something to do with your polylang settings since if you try to translate the site using google translate it translates the slider contents as well. Check this link and look at the dynamic string translation section. Hope this helps.
https://www.sitepoint.com/multilingual-wordpress-websites-with-polylang/

Comment: I tried to look at the options and the string translation section but found nothing to resolve the problem. And as I said I restored the previous version in case the problem came from the update.. but still nothing changed.

Comment: May I know why I got -1 ? What did I do wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here s the solution :

```
<?php if(get_locale() == 'fr_FR') : ?>
```

Actually the "get_bloginfo('language')" function stopped working since I upgraded to WordPress 4.6 and to Polylang 2.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it with php I resolved the problem with css: I put both english and french sliders in my header template with different classes and "display:none" the slider I don't want for each frontpage:

```
.page-id-94 .smartslider-en {

     display:none;
}

.page-id-7386 .smartslider-fr {

     display:none;
}
```

Please answer if you find a solution with php only.